# Is it better choice to use both AngularJS and ASP.Net MVC for developing ecommerce website?

Tags: mvc, asp.net, angularjs, e-commerce

I know about MVC, But I don't have such experience with AngularJS. But both has **controller and View**.

To develope like e-commerce site, is it good choice to choose AngularJS to do filtering with brands, or color, etc.

I hope most of the e-commerce site are using SPA(Single page application).

> When I read about AngularJS, it is also having controller as same as ASP.Net MVC, But the difference is AngularJS will perform in **Client side** and Asp.Net MVC will perform in **Server side**

Let's take an example. If my site having the images of mobile, when user do filter, it has to reload within a page but without reloading the entire page and bring the data from server. So to achieve this, after user select the filter, the Asp.Net's MVC's view having AngularJS will call the angularjs's controller, then that controller will call the mvc's controller method, and it will bring the records with certain amount of images and it will be posted back to the same page

Is it good scenario?. Can you give me your advice?.. Thanks

Comment: It's not the best way, but you can use that

Answer (score 2):

I would use something other than ASP.NET and Angular.js in my Opinion.
But filtering data can be **server** based or **client** based.

If you want high performance reactivity, I would recommend Vue.JS
It's easiest to start and has reactive interface.

**Vue.js** is focused on the ViewModel layer of the MVVM pattern. It connects the View and the Model via two way data bindings. Actual DOM manipulations and output formatting are abstracted away into Directives and Filters.

But If you really want ASP.NET and Angular.JS
You can see this link here:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/filter-data-in-Asp-Net-application-using-angularjs/

Answer (score -3):

You have to be tough with yourself regarding requirements.

With a commercial e-commerce site your requirements might go like this:

1. is that people can buy stuff 24/7 on any browser or mobile device from anywhere.
2. is converting people who browse the site into buyers by making it super easy, ie fewest clicks and super fast load times to signup and purchase
3. is being top in google.
4. is that you can support as many users as possible on the cheapest server infrastructure.

....

999. is cool interactive features

You may find that Single Page App frameworks enable #999 but work against #1,2,3 and 4

Comment: -1: Just a vague opinion. Doesn't address the question in any useful way.

Comment: sorry @kevin I think the question is too broad for a definitive answer. Yes you can use asp + angular to make an e-commerce site, but the devils in the detail. You may find that you want static pages as well

Comment: yes, it's too broad. It's just waiting for that last close vote.